# iOS storyboard - Auto Layout won't resize and reposition subviews

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, storyboard

I don't want to set a Y position constraint because I need the views to be relative to each other, since I have a UITextView that has to and *should* dynamically change its value based on how many lines of text are in it. It does not do this though. I can FORCE it to do it by calling sizeToFit() on the UITextView, but then it overlaps the views below.

Xcode nags me to reduce ambiguity and there are red lines all over the view controller, but it doesn't make any sense for me to manually have a Y position constraint if that has to be dynamic.

So my question is how do I
1. Make my UITextView resize its height after the number of lines of text increases
2. Make the views below it get pushed down automatically so the UITextView does not overlap them.

I've read multiple answers and have managed to do 1 but not the other.

Solution in Swift:

```
let sizeThatFitsTextView = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, textView.frame.size.height))
textViewHeightConstraint.constant = sizeThatFitsTextView.height
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `Disable the scroll of Textview` from storyboard or by coding.

2) Create an `outlet` for `textview's height constraint`. Change the height constraint programmatically from textView delegate method when text change occur based on calculation.

```
CGSize sizeThatFitsTextView = [TextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(TextView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)];

TextViewHeightConstraint.constant = sizeThatFitsTextView.height;
```

Comment: @Questioner Welcome :-)